# iPhone (iOS 5) forcing portrait from landscape and going back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, landscape-portrait

I'm working on application for iOS 5 and I have one controller which needs to be pushed in portrait view. It's quite tricky to push controller in portrait mode from the landscape but finally I figured out how to do that. I show controller by `presentModalViewController` or by `pushViewController` and inside the controller I override `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` metod.

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

It works fine just it has one problem. Below is the scenario.

1. User holds the device in landscape mode and current controller is correctly shown in landscape mode
2. User make some action and the portrait only controller appears (as modal controller and in portrait mode)
3. User close the modal controller
4. Previous controller which works in landscape is now in portrait, but user still holds his device in landscape ---> This is the problem

I tried to fix it by calling `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]` but it doesn't help.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your saying that working with IOS 5**, but `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()` method **available from IOS 6** onwards only.

To solve your problem **(in ios5)** you needs to override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation()` method as like this...

in targeted view controller **(View controller which you needed in portrait mode)** as like this....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

in the current view controller **(View controller which you needed in landscape mode)**  as like this....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer Bhanu, I have seen this several times already but it never helps me with forcing some controller in different interface orientation...

Comment: Updated the answer check it. @Michal

Answer (score 1):

I hope you get a better, working solution I did a nasty thing to get working. My problem it was I needed to support from 4.3 to 6.0. Some pushModal functions has changed radically, become deprecated and so on, also there are changes at rotations.

I wrote a RoatatingViewController and  I have added to the root. Than I have added push modals and pushviewconcollers, as desired. 
When I need to pop, than I do a check: if the desired component on the stack is in desired orientation than is good, no changes. Otherwise: pop the landscape and push the portait instance and copy the landscape data to portait.

It isn't nice, it isn't memory efficient, but is working without crashing with all iOS versions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and  it doesn't work for me, maybe I get it wrong. Can you please explain when do you pop the landscape controller and push the portrait one?

Comment: What I do is that in viewWillDisappear of modal controller I pop controller which should be in landscape and push it again. Is that right or I get the idea wrong?

Comment: @Michal it isn't just 2 line of the code...there are a couple of classes. Also need to register to notification to get the device orientation change notification, and it depends on the OS version too. sorry to see it doesn't helped for you!